# wp wp_register_script function results type parameter missing

Tags: php, functions, wp-register-script

I used the following code

```
    wp_register_script('jquery', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/jquery.js', false, '',false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

It includes the script as

```
 <script src="http://siteurl.com/wp-content/themes/testtheme/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Here how to add the type parameter as `type="text/javascript"`

Because it creates an error in IE browser

Please help to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you enqueue core jQuery library? Does it work?

Comment: By using the above code it is working fine in all browsers except i.e. 

In i.e browser it shows an error as "object expected" in the line of $(doc...ready... line

Comment: What happens if you do not use template jQuery file? But only use `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` in your `functions.php`. Does that add `type="text/javascript"` to script tag?

Comment: it didn't add the jquery file , if we use wp_enqueue_script('jquery') alone

Comment: Then there is some issue with your WordPress. Replace `wp-admin` and `wp-includes` folder completely.

Comment: Additionally to Robert comments, if your document is HTML5 **the type attribute is optional** and default to text/javascrpt. Your problem is not with that.

Comment: what version of Wordpress are you using?

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to add Jquery lib for your theme then consider using **wp_head()** just above closing **< /head >** tag. Wordpress automatically adds a Jquery by default. You need not to add the lib file/ url manually.

Comment: Using `wp_head()` doesn't enqueue jQuery automatically. jQuery is registered by WordPress core but the theme still needs to enqueue it by using `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` via [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) action hook.

Comment: oops! i didn't notice that.